# Page not found error for custom module pages

Tags: orchardcms

I had some issue while I was trying to debug something in VS. So I closed Visual Studio, deleted the .suo file and opened the solution again. When I tried to run the project, I got a 404 page not found error. I deleted the appdata folder, deleted the database tables, and setup orchard again. No luck. All the Orchard pages work fine (home page, admin dashboard..) but none of the pages in any of my custom modules works, I get 404 error for all of them. I checked admin dashboard, all the modules are enabled.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your module probably doesn't build.

Comment: I am able to build the solution, including all the custom modules. There were no errors. If there were any errors, the modules wouldn't show up in Dashboard - Modules, right?

Comment: Anything in app_data\logs?